# MYSQL selecting new column based on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, left-join

I'm still working through some kinks with MySQL so any help will be appreciated.

I have 3 tables -- equipment, states, zones.

```
equipment:
+---------------+------+------------+
| current_state |  id  | ...columns | 
+---------------+------+------------+

states:
+----------+-------------+
| state    | zone_id     |
+----------+-------------+

zones:
+-----+------+
| id  | zone | 
+-----+------+
```

In equipment, there is one current_state per row.

In states, there is one zone_id per row.

In zones, there is one zone per row.

I would like to JOIN the three tables as a subquery select statement (not even sure if that's a thing) and have the output return as 1 alias'd column among the other columns I'm selecting

```
+--------------+-------------+
| current_zone | ....columns |
+--------------+-------------+
```

A sample expected output is:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+
|    c_id    |    g_id     |  e_id  | equipment_type   | impressionId | email   |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1234       | ABC1234     | 0001   | VEST             | 2032         |ab@yc.com|
| 1234       | 1234ABC     | 0001   | SHIRT            | 4372         |ab@yc.com|
| 1234       | DCBA123     | 0001   | CAN              | 4372         |ab@yc.com|
| 1234       | DCBA321     | 0001   | JACKET           | ab@yc.com    |ab@yw.com| 
| 4567       | abc321d     | 0002   | SHIRT            | 2032         |db@yw.com|
| 4567       | cba123d     | 0002   | CAN              | 4372         |db@yw.com|
| 4567       | def4rg4     | 0002   | JEANS            | 3210         |db@yw.com|
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+
```

The current query has multiple joins already referring to the zones and states table in order to determine a different value:

```
SELECT equipment.*,
    ...
    FROM equipment
    LEFT JOIN c on equipment.c_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN g on equipment.g_id = g.id
    LEFT JOIN states on g.state = states.state
    LEFT JOIN zones on zones.id = states.zone_id
```

Essentially, what I want to do is create a subquery in order to create a new column based on the results of the three joins, something like this:

```
SELECT equipment.*,
    (SELECT
        equipment.current_state
        FROM equipment
        LEFT JOIN equipment.current_state = states.state
        LEFT JOIN zones.id = states.zone_id
    ) as current_zone,
    ...
```

This is even possible? Am I trying to select a new column in the wrong place?

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with using `join`s in the `from` clause?

Comment: So I'm already using the join in the from clause. Is it possible to join tables in multiple locations for multiple values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, as I mentioned, I'm already joining states and zones through different columns in order to obtain a specific value, but I also want to get a different value based on a different join of the same tables

Comment: You can join them still, just give them an alias so they're different from the previous ones

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, that's a great point - but how would I select the newly created column? i.e. since I am already selecting the specific columns i need, how do I set an alias to select the new column I need?

Comment: What is *c* and *g* tables? You explained the other three with clear labels.

Comment: c and g are different tables that aren't really relevant to the question. They are included here to indicate that the query I am currently running is selecting multiple values from multiple tables

Comment: "what I want to do is create a subquery in order to create a new column based on the results of the three joins" -- This is called a "Scalar Subquery". Scalar subqueries are quite useful and are executed once per resulting row; this can result in a performance degradation if your main query returns a lot of rows and/or if the scalar subquery is not optimized or lacks indexes. Also, a scalar subquery -- as its name implies -- is limited to return at most one row; only zero or one rows are allowed; if the scalar subquery returns more than a single row, then the whole SQL statement will fail.

Comment: @TheImpaler, thanks for that info! I'll look it up right now. Performance isn't going to be an issue (this is a one-time operation to transfer data in a specific format), but I think the row constraints are where I'm going wrong since my current implementation is returning the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TheImpaler I was able to clear up my Scalar Subquery. In my eyes, I thought I had to create another join based on the properties I wanted when in reality all I had to do was create a conditional scalar subquery:

```
SELECT equipment.*,
(SELECT zones.zone
    FROM zones
    WHERE equipment.current_state = states.state
    AND zones.id = states.zone_id
) as current_zone,
...
```